# Why is IOS folder too huge when compared to android folder in React-Native?

Tags: react-native

I have developed an app in react native, but the project folder is too large(1.2GB) to upload into git and the IOS folder itself holding 0.9GB.I have done the following steps to overcome the issue

Steps Followed :-

1. Deleted Android and IOS folders from project folder.
2. Uploaded and Downloaded the project code using git.
3. Later run the commands like npm install and react-native upgrade

After running the above commands to generate IOS and Android folders, we are supposed to run Android version, but facing issue with IOS.

So...I request you to let me know the proper process of uploading code into git such that i can run both Android and IOS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `.gitignore` and make sure at a minimum that the build  and node_modules folders are not included. For me 95% of the size is from that.

[example gitignore](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/.gitignore)